# How to implement operator delete for C++11 impostors of C "classes"?

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, operator-overloading, porting

I'm trying to write C++11 impostors (as best termed by @jrok, because these classes have no fields like wrappers do) for bunch of C "classes", similarly to this:

```
extern "C" {
  struct cfoo;
  cfoo * cfoo_new();
  void cfoo_free(cfoo *);
  int cfoo_bar(cfoo *, int);
} // extern "C" {
class Foo final {
    Foo() = delete;                        // Prevents
    Foo(Foo &&) = delete;                  // construction
    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;             // of this
    Foo & operator=(Foo &&) = delete;      // C++
    Foo & operator=(const Foo &) = delete; // object
public: /* Methods: */
    int bar(int v) noexcept { return cfoo_bar(cPtr(), v); }
    cfoo * cPtr() noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<cfoo *>(this); }
    static Foo * create() {
       cfoo * const f = cfoo_new();
       if (!f) throw std::bad_alloc();
       return reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(f);
    }
    // No member fields! No double dereference! No extra memory!
}; // class Foo {
```

However, in C++11 code I also want to do something like:

```
Foo * foo = Foo::create();
foo->bar(42);
delete foo;                                 // (1)
{
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> pFoo(Foo::create()); // no custom deleter!
  pFoo->bar(3);
} // pFoo goes out of scope                 // (2)
```

so that (1) and (2) would only call `ctest_free(x->cPtr())` where `Test * x` is the pointer passed to the `delete` operator.

What would be the proper/safest way to implement this in C++11?

**Edit:** Thank you for your answers so far, but please lets keep this on topic and refrain from rant on coding practices. Please just answer the question, tell me why this is impossible to archieve, or show me where my code has undefined behaviour according to ISO/IEC 14482/2011.

Comment: Your class `Foo` should have a memeber `cfoo *` instead of casting between `Foo*` and `cfoo*`.

Comment: Good observation, but I'd like to do without any members, amending my post in a minute.

Comment: These are "impostors", not "wrappers".

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this without any member fields? What conceivable advantage do you think you will gain from this?

Comment: Erm, just to be clear,  "impostors" is not an established term, it was a joke (that happens to be somewhat true).

Comment: This is the plainest of UB. You are invoking a non-static member function of `Foo` on something that's not actually one.

Comment: @Puppy Where is the undefined behaviour?

Comment: Just write a wrapper and let the compiler optimize away the (trivial) abstraction. [Check the generated assembly](http://goo.gl/ajqGPw). Instantiations of `Foo`s are replaced with the single `cfoo*`. No extra memory, etc.

Comment: You call `Foo::bar` from a `cfoo` object.

Comment: @tclamb The compiler doesn't optimize this away.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wouldn't it then be better to use the C function directly? And wouldn't this beat the whole purpose of writing a C++ interface for these?

Comment: @jotik Yes, it does... Compare the assembly I linked above to [using the C interface](http://goo.gl/TYYD83). They are _literally identical_.

Comment: Same assembly for [C++ interface](http://goo.gl/Mn7MH8) and [C interface](http://goo.gl/TYYD83) :-)

Comment: @tclamb Thats because you inline. The compiler is NOT guaranteed by ISO/IEC 14882 to do that. Lets keep this a pure C++ question and compiler/platform agnostic.

Comment: @jotik: If you want to keep it "pure C++" and rely only on things "guaranteed by ISO/IEC 14882", then the answer _is_ "this is UB" and that's the end of it!

Comment: @jotik Okay, I went ahead and quoted the relevant part of the standard in an answer.

Comment: You cannot have it both ways.  If this is a pure C++ question, then your `reinterpret_cast` followed by any use of the object is completely undefined behavior.  If we go with the member pointer case, your compiler is going to have sizeof(`Foo`) to be sizeof(`cfoo*`) in practice, and if your `Foo` is standard layout it is basically guaranteed to be nothing but a pointer to `cfoo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is undefined behavior because you are invoking a non-static member function of `Foo` on an object that is not a `Foo` (a `cfoo`). The relevant standard-ese is §9.3.1/2:

> If a non-static member function of a class **`X`** is called for an object that is not of type **`X`**, or of a type derived from **`X`**, the behavior is undefined.

There is no exception made for member functions of empty classes.

---

The safest and proper way to do what you are trying is to write a wrapper type, as many others have pointed out already. For example:

```
class Foo {
    std::unique_ptr<cfoo, void(*)(cfoo*)> p;
public:
    Foo() : p{cfoo_new(), cfoo_free} { if (!p) throw std::bad_alloc{}; }
    int bar(int i) noexcept { return cfoo_bar(p.get(), i); }
};
```

Comparing its usage to the C interface:

```
// Using the C interface
{
    cfoo* foo = cfoo_new();
    if (!foo) throw std::bad_alloc{};
    cfoo_bar(foo, 42);
    cfoo_free(foo);
}

// Using a C++ wrapper
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar(42);
}
```

This will be zero overhead over the C interface when using any optimizing compiler. For example, the assembly output by GCC is *identical* for both blocks above.

Comment: It is not entirely true that there is always zero overhead over the C interface as you can see in my answer there is an extra instruction involved when passing a reference to the wrapper class to a non inlined function. So the C interface has a traceable speed advantage in one case at least at the cost of throwing away all of the memory safety of the C++ class.

Comment: Ah, so sad! Without §9.3.1/2 this would have been a great way to interface with C.

Answer (score 4):

```
// No member fields! No double dereference! No extra memory!
```

You seem to think that having a member in your class will somehow increase your memory usage. This is simply not going to be true. Compare your code sample:

```
Foo * foo = Foo::create();
foo->bar(42);
```

To what it should look like:

```
Foo foo;
foo.bar();
```

In the first we are using stack memory to store `foo` which will be `sizeof(Foo*)`, in the second we are using stack memory to store `foo` which will be `sizeof(Foo)`. If `Foo` contains one member of either `Foo*` type or `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` type then how big will `Foo` be? That's right, it will be `Foo*` big.

The key difference is that the second example is exception safe, safe from memory leak errors, clear and compact.

As for the worry about extra de-referencing, how many de-references are in your `foo->bar()` example? No de-references happen within the function itself. How many occur in `foo.bar()` where `bar` is defined as:

```
int bar(int v) noexcept { return cfoo_bar(p.get(), v); }
```

by Jarod42? Again no de-references happen within the function itself, only once `cfoo_bar` uses that pointer.

**Edit:** So from reading the comments you later left on the question it appears to be that what you are *actually* optimizing for is the overhead of passing a reference to the wrapper object to a function. Yes this does have some overhead. If I define:

```
void foobar(cfoo * f)
{
  cfoo_bar(f, 0);
}
```

Then `g++ -O3` generates:

```
foobar(cfoo*):
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    jmp cfoo_bar
```

Whereas:

```
void foobar(Foo& f)
{
  f.bar(0);
}
```

generates:

```
foobar(Foo&):
    movq    8(%rdi), %rdi
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    jmp cfoo_bar
```

But this is simply the price you pay for the deterministic destruction that comes with C++ classes. Your proposed solution will indeed produce the same assembly as the C version but will have the same memory safety problems as it as well. That's not to say coding in a C style is ever wrong when you do need that extra instruction of performance but you do not get it for free.

*N.B.* I had to `__attribute__((noinline))` the above functions just to prevent the compiler from inlining them and thus eliminating the overhead.

Comment: 1337 C++ hax0r skillz are be satisfactory, thank you very much for your sincere concern! Secondly, if `Foo` were to contain a pointer field, it should instead be called `FooUniquePtr` or something, because it would otherwise mislead programmers into believing a single pointer dereference occurs. Thirdly, by having no accessible constructors for `Foo` I can pretty-much guarantee that `sizeof(Foo)` has no reasonable applications. Finally, regardless of my sanity, it would have been polite of you to answer my original question by saying whether what I'm asking for is impossible to archieve.

Answer (score 3):

Following may help:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : p(cfoo_new()) {
       if (!p) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
    }
    ~Foo() { cfoo_free(p); }

    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator = (const Foo&) = delete;

    int bar(int v) noexcept { return cfoo_bar(p, v); }
private:
    cfoo* p;
};
```

Or even better with `std::unique_ptr` as mentionned by quantdev

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : p(cfoo_new(), cfoo_free) {
       if (!p) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
    }
    int bar(int v) noexcept { return cfoo_bar(p.get(), v); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, void(*)(Foo*)> p;
};
```

And so your calling code becomes:

```
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar(42);
} // foo goes out of scope
{
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> pFoo(new Foo()); // no custom deleter!
  pFoo->bar(3);
} // pFoo goes out of scope
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help. I'm explicitly trying to avoid instantiation of `Foo`, if possible (and nobody here has yet proved this to be impossible).

Comment: Why ? We don't see the gain expected.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the double dereference. Programmers using this "impostor" interface will probably write functions like `void f(Foo &);` causing double dereferences. However I need to squeeze this to max performance. Unfortunately, explaining the reasons for this wouldn't easily fit on StackOverflow and would take too much time to write down at the moment. ;( I know that what I'm looking for is rather exquisite. Maybe I should have been more clear about this in my question.

Comment: @jotik: With `Foo foo;` you don't have overhead in the call with `foo.bar(42)`

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to force programmers pass `Foo` by value.

Comment: IME "just trust me I need this" causes space rockets to explode in mid-flight.